# Get list of all matches

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex, python-re

Im tryng to get a full list of colors (In hexa) in a large string like this:

```
'''
#C4F407      // valid color
#ZZZZZZ      // invalid color
Hello there! // invalid color
#F08         // invalid color
45E097       // invalid color
#FF00AA      // valid color
...
'''
```

So i wrote this regex expression to find them:
`^#([A-F]|[0-9]){6}$`
, and it matches strings that have only one color. (I mean `re.search('^#([A-F]|[0-9]){6}$', '#C456F7'))` matches `#C456F7`)

But, when i use
`re.findall('^#([A-F]|[0-9]){6}$', largeString)`
i got
`[]`
when i supose to get `['#C4F407', '#FF00AA']`

How can I get a list of all the well written colors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are searching only on string bounds. `^` matches only line starts and `$` line ends.

Since your string contains more data, `^` and `$` will not match.

Change your regex to `(#(?:[A-F]|[0-9]){6})` and it will work fine:

```
>>> re.findall(r'(#(?:[A-F]|[0-9]){6})', largeString)
['#C4F407', '#FF00AA']
```

Note that I included a `?:` in the inner parenthesis and I included an outer parenthesis. That way, we regex will not capture what is inside the inner parenthesis, but only full colors.

Also note that I used `r''` for the regex string. It indicates that the python interpreter should not interpret escaped characters such as `\b` and leave them to the regex. I recommend using those on all regex strings.

To avoid matching beyond the sixth character, you can add a border `\b` to the end of your regex, such as `(#(?:[A-F]|[0-9]){6})\b`:

```python
>>> largeString = '''
#C4F407      // valid color
#ZZZZZZ      // invalid color
Hello there! // invalid color
#F08         // invalid color
45E097       // invalid color
#FF00AA      // valid color
#0000000     // invalid color
...
'''
>>> re.findall(r'(#(?:[A-F]|[0-9]){6})\b', largeString)
['#C4F407', '#FF00AA']
```

Comment: Oh, thank you so much, it works! But when i have a more than 7 chars (#0000008) it matches #000000. How can i only match exactly 7 character color codes?

Comment: You can add a `\b` to the end of the regex. I will edit my answer to include it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this regex.

```
#([A-F]|[0-9]){6}
```